# Delphi 10.4 stores default VirtualTree's default properties in .dfm file

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, delphi-10.4-sydney

After updating to Delphi 10.4 Sydney, my instances of TVirtualStringTree store their Colors.XYZ properties in the dfm files, although I left these on the default values:

[image]

In [VirtualTrees.pas](https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView/blob/master/Source/VirtualTrees.pas), these color values have a default value, which normally means these shall not be written to a dfm file:

```
  published
    property BorderColor: TColor index cBorderColor read GetColor write SetColor default clBtnFace;
    property DisabledColor: TColor index cDisabledColor read GetColor write SetColor default clBtnShadow;
    property DropMarkColor: TColor index cDropMarkColor read GetColor write SetColor default clHighlight;
    ...
```

How to get rid of these default colors in the dfm files?

Comment: The default values in a property declaration mean that the streaming system compares those values with the actual values and if only  they are the same, then they are not written.

Comment: So the streaming system cannot see the defaults of these properties any longer? I wonder if that has something to do with the fact that "Colors" is an object itself.

Comment: Does this also happen in a new project or only in your old project?

Comment: @Anse what iamjoosy is trying to say is that the *constructor* for the `Colors` property object must assign values to the sub-properties that match the defaults declared on the sub-properties. Is there such a constructor, and does it set the correct property values? Note that in your DFM example, the `DisabledColors` is saved as `clGray` but its default is `clBtnShadow`. That implies a mismatch in the constructor, or something else in the `Colors` object is changing the sub-property values after construction. Same with the other properties being saved as numbers instead of text aliases

Comment: A related question on the Embarcadero forum explains a possible culprit: https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/general-development/f/rad-studio-general/72519/problem-of-the-colors-property-of-tvirtualstringtree-in-delphi-10-4

Comment: @SilverWarior these values are also in a dfm file of a blank new project with a VirtualTree dropped on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is result of the fact that `StyleServices.IsSystemStyle` used to return True in the designer former Delphi version, now in 10.4 it returns False.

This will get fixed soon in Virtual TreeView: https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView/issues/975

Answer (score 0):

The root cause probably is that the form designer uses:

'Windows' style in Delphi 10.3 Rio, so `StyleServices.IsSystemStyle` returns `True`

'Windows10' style in Delphi 10.4 Rio, so `StyleServices.IsSystemStyle` returns `False`

So many component packages are affected by that change and update the component colors in the .DFM files. For example in TMS VCL UI Pack there is this code all over the place `(LStyle.Name <> 'Windows')`